# Print pattern, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to print this pattern using for loop in javascript for n number for *'s 
1 2 3\n 
4 5 6 \n
7 8 9

Answer (score 0):

You make the for loop and check if the number is % 3 then you also print "\n".

Comment: \n means next line, not it mean to print '\n'